# Tables and figures at the end of each chapter

Tags: floats, positioning

Right now I have all my figures and tables at the end of my dissertation. To do this I'm using this:

```
\usepackage[nomarkers]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\mbox{}}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\vfill}
```

I need to have the tables figures at the end of each chapter, and I need to number them using the number of the chapter. That is, 1.1, 2.1, etc.

My document class is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
```

Can you tell me how to do what I need?

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nomarkers]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\mbox{}}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\vfill}
\usepackage[]{threeparttable}


\title{Minimal Working Example}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter[Something 1]{Bla bla bla}
\section{Section 1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam non turpis nec sapien gravida suscipit. Maecenas eget libero pretium, rhoncus ante id, suscipit eros. Maecenas at turpis condimentum, iaculis justo id, tempor urna. Integer vitae tincidunt magna, non rhoncus justo. Curabitur tincidunt massa in est fermentum, ac varius augue porta. Ut at leo eu dolor elementum scelerisque. Integer eu rhoncus nibh.


\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Treatment effect on Quiz 6 outcomes and choices} 
  \label{eg1}

    \begin{threeparttable}

\begin{tabular}{rllll}
  \hline
 & Treatment & Control & 90\% Confidence Interval & p-value \\ 
  \hline
  maxGrade\tnote{a} & 0.8506 & 0.7809 & (0.0154, 0.124) & 0.0347 \\ 
  firstGrade\tnote{b} & 0.5278 & 0.4966 & (-0.005, 0.0673) & 0.1561 \\ 
  Attempts\tnote{c} & 0.2461 & 0.2241 & (0.0059, 0.0381) & 0.0247 \\ 
  Took Q6\tnote{d} & 0.1002 & 0.093 & (0.001, 0.0135) & 0.058 \\ 
  Procrastination\tnote{e} & 102.9237 & 105.0334 & (-6.8086, 2.5892) & 0.4601 \\ 
  n & 12061 & 12061 &  &  \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item \footnotesize{Sample: Students who stated their intention to complete all the work needed to obtain the certificate}
\item [a]\footnotesize{First attempt grade}
\item [b]\footnotesize{Best attempt grade}
\item [c]\footnotesize{Numbers of attempts}
\item [d]\footnotesize{Dummy equal to 1 if the student attempted the Quiz}
\item [e]\footnotesize{Number of hours between the quiz publication and student first attempt}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}


Nullam justo arcu, semper id rutrum sit amet, volutpat ac mauris. Praesent venenatis, nulla a tristique lobortis, erat quam molestie tortor, ac fringilla magna purus ac mi. Nunc ornare felis et enim hendrerit, eget suscipit nisl tempus. Curabitur pharetra nibh nisl, imperdiet convallis lectus rutrum elementum. Maecenas blandit ipsum sit amet nulla posuere aliquet. Sed hendrerit et elit vitae ornare. Praesent malesuada metus ac sem faucibus, sed cursus mi egestas. Sed ut massa nec nisi ullamcorper auctor.

\chapter[Something 2]{Bla bla bla}
\section{Section 1}

Sed adipiscing hendrerit ultricies. Etiam pretium ultrices aliquet. Nullam tortor purus, elementum non dictum non, condimentum ac nibh. Ut porta erat fringilla metus condimentum, in hendrerit sapien molestie. Aenean varius consequat arcu, eget aliquam justo. Morbi aliquam risus quis augue tempor vulputate. Ut ut dui cursus, ultricies est vitae, consequat ipsum. Vivamus rutrum vulputate varius. 

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Treatment effect on Quiz 6 outcomes and choices} 
  \label{eg2}

    \begin{threeparttable}

\begin{tabular}{rllll}
  \hline
 & Treatment & Control & 90\% Confidence Interval & p-value \\ 
  \hline
  maxGrade\tnote{a} & 0.8506 & 0.7809 & (0.0154, 0.124) & 0.0347 \\ 
  firstGrade\tnote{b} & 0.5278 & 0.4966 & (-0.005, 0.0673) & 0.1561 \\ 
  Attempts\tnote{c} & 0.2461 & 0.2241 & (0.0059, 0.0381) & 0.0247 \\ 
  Took Q6\tnote{d} & 0.1002 & 0.093 & (0.001, 0.0135) & 0.058 \\ 
  Procrastination\tnote{e} & 102.9237 & 105.0334 & (-6.8086, 2.5892) & 0.4601 \\ 
  n & 12061 & 12061 &  &  \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item \footnotesize{Sample: Students who stated their intention to complete all the work needed to obtain the certificate}
\item [a]\footnotesize{First attempt grade}
\item [b]\footnotesize{Best attempt grade}
\item [c]\footnotesize{Numbers of attempts}
\item [d]\footnotesize{Dummy equal to 1 if the student attempted the Quiz}
\item [e]\footnotesize{Number of hours between the quiz publication and student first attempt}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}


Vivamus cursus tortor ut eros egestas imperdiet. Morbi sed diam ac nisl vestibulum volutpat. Etiam vestibulum neque ac justo suscipit, ac pretium metus eleifend. Duis sed sem lorem. Etiam pellentesque volutpat sapien, non pellentesque urna varius nec.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\processdelayedfloats` at the end of every chapter:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nomarkers,nolists]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\mbox{}}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\vfill}
\usepackage[]{threeparttable}


\title{Minimal Working Example}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter[Something 1]{Bla bla bla}
\section{Section 1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam non turpis nec sapien gravida suscipit. Maecenas eget libero pretium, rhoncus ante id, suscipit eros. Maecenas at turpis condimentum, iaculis justo id, tempor urna. Integer vitae tincidunt magna, non rhoncus justo. Curabitur tincidunt massa in est fermentum, ac varius augue porta. Ut at leo eu dolor elementum scelerisque. Integer eu rhoncus nibh.


\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Treatment effect on Quiz 6 outcomes and choices} 
  \label{eg1}

    \begin{threeparttable}

\begin{tabular}{rllll}
  \hline
 & Treatment & Control & 90\% Confidence Interval & p-value \\ 
  \hline
  maxGrade\tnote{a} & 0.8506 & 0.7809 & (0.0154, 0.124) & 0.0347 \\ 
  firstGrade\tnote{b} & 0.5278 & 0.4966 & (-0.005, 0.0673) & 0.1561 \\ 
  Attempts\tnote{c} & 0.2461 & 0.2241 & (0.0059, 0.0381) & 0.0247 \\ 
  Took Q6\tnote{d} & 0.1002 & 0.093 & (0.001, 0.0135) & 0.058 \\ 
  Procrastination\tnote{e} & 102.9237 & 105.0334 & (-6.8086, 2.5892) & 0.4601 \\ 
  n & 12061 & 12061 &  &  \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item \footnotesize{Sample: Students who stated their intention to complete all the work needed to obtain the certificate}
\item [a]\footnotesize{First attempt grade}
\item [b]\footnotesize{Best attempt grade}
\item [c]\footnotesize{Numbers of attempts}
\item [d]\footnotesize{Dummy equal to 1 if the student attempted the Quiz}
\item [e]\footnotesize{Number of hours between the quiz publication and student first attempt}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}


Nullam justo arcu, semper id rutrum sit amet, volutpat ac mauris. Praesent venenatis, nulla a tristique lobortis, erat quam molestie tortor, ac fringilla magna purus ac mi. Nunc ornare felis et enim hendrerit, eget suscipit nisl tempus. Curabitur pharetra nibh nisl, imperdiet convallis lectus rutrum elementum. Maecenas blandit ipsum sit amet nulla posuere aliquet. Sed hendrerit et elit vitae ornare. Praesent malesuada metus ac sem faucibus, sed cursus mi egestas. Sed ut massa nec nisi ullamcorper auctor.

\processdelayedfloats

\chapter[Something 2]{Bla bla bla}
\section{Section 1}

Sed adipiscing hendrerit ultricies. Etiam pretium ultrices aliquet. Nullam tortor purus, elementum non dictum non, condimentum ac nibh. Ut porta erat fringilla metus condimentum, in hendrerit sapien molestie. Aenean varius consequat arcu, eget aliquam justo. Morbi aliquam risus quis augue tempor vulputate. Ut ut dui cursus, ultricies est vitae, consequat ipsum. Vivamus rutrum vulputate varius. 

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Treatment effect on Quiz 6 outcomes and choices} 
  \label{eg2}

    \begin{threeparttable}

\begin{tabular}{rllll}
  \hline
 & Treatment & Control & 90\% Confidence Interval & p-value \\ 
  \hline
  maxGrade\tnote{a} & 0.8506 & 0.7809 & (0.0154, 0.124) & 0.0347 \\ 
  firstGrade\tnote{b} & 0.5278 & 0.4966 & (-0.005, 0.0673) & 0.1561 \\ 
  Attempts\tnote{c} & 0.2461 & 0.2241 & (0.0059, 0.0381) & 0.0247 \\ 
  Took Q6\tnote{d} & 0.1002 & 0.093 & (0.001, 0.0135) & 0.058 \\ 
  Procrastination\tnote{e} & 102.9237 & 105.0334 & (-6.8086, 2.5892) & 0.4601 \\ 
  n & 12061 & 12061 &  &  \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item \footnotesize{Sample: Students who stated their intention to complete all the work needed to obtain the certificate}
\item [a]\footnotesize{First attempt grade}
\item [b]\footnotesize{Best attempt grade}
\item [c]\footnotesize{Numbers of attempts}
\item [d]\footnotesize{Dummy equal to 1 if the student attempted the Quiz}
\item [e]\footnotesize{Number of hours between the quiz publication and student first attempt}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}


Vivamus cursus tortor ut eros egestas imperdiet. Morbi sed diam ac nisl vestibulum volutpat. Etiam vestibulum neque ac justo suscipit, ac pretium metus eleifend. Duis sed sem lorem. Etiam pellentesque volutpat sapien, non pellentesque urna varius nec.

\processdelayedfloats

\end{document}
```

### Update:

The `enfloat` package, however, doesn't make provision for partial lists when using `\processdelayedfloats` but this can be solved using the `features` provided by the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package. Use `\startlist{lot}` right after each `\chapter` with delayed tables and then use `\MakePartialLoT` at the point in which you want the partial LoT to appear (typically right before `\processdelayedfloats`). I defined the command as

```
\newcommand\MakePartialLot{%
  \printlist{lot}{}{\chapter*{\listtablename\ for \chaptername~\thechapter}\par}
}
```

but you can change the definition to suit your needs.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nomarkers,nolists]{endfloat}
\usepackage[]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\mbox{}}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\vfill}

\newcommand\MakePartialLot{%
  \printlist{lot}{}{\chapter*{\listtablename\ for \chaptername~\thechapter}\par}
}

\title{Minimal Working Example}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter[Something 1]{Bla bla bla}
\startlist{lot}
\section{Section 1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam non turpis nec sapien gravida suscipit. Maecenas eget libero pretium, rhoncus ante id, suscipit eros. Maecenas at turpis condimentum, iaculis justo id, tempor urna. Integer vitae tincidunt magna, non rhoncus justo. Curabitur tincidunt massa in est fermentum, ac varius augue porta. Ut at leo eu dolor elementum scelerisque. Integer eu rhoncus nibh.


\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Treatment effect on Quiz 6 outcomes and choices} 
  \label{eg1}

    \begin{threeparttable}

\begin{tabular}{rllll}
  \hline
 & Treatment & Control & 90\% Confidence Interval & p-value \\ 
  \hline
  maxGrade\tnote{a} & 0.8506 & 0.7809 & (0.0154, 0.124) & 0.0347 \\ 
  firstGrade\tnote{b} & 0.5278 & 0.4966 & (-0.005, 0.0673) & 0.1561 \\ 
  Attempts\tnote{c} & 0.2461 & 0.2241 & (0.0059, 0.0381) & 0.0247 \\ 
  Took Q6\tnote{d} & 0.1002 & 0.093 & (0.001, 0.0135) & 0.058 \\ 
  Procrastination\tnote{e} & 102.9237 & 105.0334 & (-6.8086, 2.5892) & 0.4601 \\ 
  n & 12061 & 12061 &  &  \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item \footnotesize{Sample: Students who stated their intention to complete all the work needed to obtain the certificate}
\item [a]\footnotesize{First attempt grade}
\item [b]\footnotesize{Best attempt grade}
\item [c]\footnotesize{Numbers of attempts}
\item [d]\footnotesize{Dummy equal to 1 if the student attempted the Quiz}
\item [e]\footnotesize{Number of hours between the quiz publication and student first attempt}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}


Nullam justo arcu, semper id rutrum sit amet, volutpat ac mauris. Praesent venenatis, nulla a tristique lobortis, erat quam molestie tortor, ac fringilla magna purus ac mi. Nunc ornare felis et enim hendrerit, eget suscipit nisl tempus. Curabitur pharetra nibh nisl, imperdiet convallis lectus rutrum elementum. Maecenas blandit ipsum sit amet nulla posuere aliquet. Sed hendrerit et elit vitae ornare. Praesent malesuada metus ac sem faucibus, sed cursus mi egestas. Sed ut massa nec nisi ullamcorper auctor.

\MakePartialLot
\processdelayedfloats

\chapter[Something 2]{Bla bla bla}
\startlist{lot}
\section{Section 1}

Sed adipiscing hendrerit ultricies. Etiam pretium ultrices aliquet. Nullam tortor purus, elementum non dictum non, condimentum ac nibh. Ut porta erat fringilla metus condimentum, in hendrerit sapien molestie. Aenean varius consequat arcu, eget aliquam justo. Morbi aliquam risus quis augue tempor vulputate. Ut ut dui cursus, ultricies est vitae, consequat ipsum. Vivamus rutrum vulputate varius. 

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Treatment effect on Quiz 6 outcomes and choices} 
  \label{eg2}

    \begin{threeparttable}

\begin{tabular}{rllll}
  \hline
 & Treatment & Control & 90\% Confidence Interval & p-value \\ 
  \hline
  maxGrade\tnote{a} & 0.8506 & 0.7809 & (0.0154, 0.124) & 0.0347 \\ 
  firstGrade\tnote{b} & 0.5278 & 0.4966 & (-0.005, 0.0673) & 0.1561 \\ 
  Attempts\tnote{c} & 0.2461 & 0.2241 & (0.0059, 0.0381) & 0.0247 \\ 
  Took Q6\tnote{d} & 0.1002 & 0.093 & (0.001, 0.0135) & 0.058 \\ 
  Procrastination\tnote{e} & 102.9237 & 105.0334 & (-6.8086, 2.5892) & 0.4601 \\ 
  n & 12061 & 12061 &  &  \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item \footnotesize{Sample: Students who stated their intention to complete all the work needed to obtain the certificate}
\item [a]\footnotesize{First attempt grade}
\item [b]\footnotesize{Best attempt grade}
\item [c]\footnotesize{Numbers of attempts}
\item [d]\footnotesize{Dummy equal to 1 if the student attempted the Quiz}
\item [e]\footnotesize{Number of hours between the quiz publication and student first attempt}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


Vivamus cursus tortor ut eros egestas imperdiet. Morbi sed diam ac nisl vestibulum volutpat. Etiam vestibulum neque ac justo suscipit, ac pretium metus eleifend. Duis sed sem lorem. Etiam pellentesque volutpat sapien, non pellentesque urna varius nec.

\MakePartialLot
\processdelayedfloats

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I do that in page 2 I have the list of tables for chapters 1 and 2, instead of just 1, and in page 5 an empty page with the title list of table instead of the list of tables for chapter 2. If I add `\usepackage[nomarkers,nolists]{endfloat}` I get no page with the list of tables. Is it possible to have a page per chapter? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ignacio yes, `endfloat` doesn't provide features for partial lists. I've updated my answer showing a possible solution to get partial list with the help of the `titletoc` package.